# Issues with mini PCIe to PCI Express x1 adapter

Tags: pci-express, adapter

I have a Gigabyte Brix GB-BXi7-4500 which comes with a **half size mini PCIe slot** already occupied by WiFi + BT card. I want to use a Magewell XI100DE-SDI video capture card which requires a host interface of **PCI Express x1**. As per my knowledge, both the mini PCIe and PCI Express x1 run the same standard but only differ slot physical sizes. I purchased **mini PCIe to PCI express adapters** and tried to connected the card to the host system. 
I also powered the adapter using a power supply from another computer. The adapter comes with a USB 2.0 port. I tried plugging in mouse / KB using the adapter USB port and they work. But i am unable to get the the card working. 
**The Gigabyte doesn't even detect the card when plugged into the PCIe x1 of the adapter**. Can somebody help me out?

Here are the links to the products.

http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4736#sp

http://www.magewell.com/xi100de-sdi/tech-specs

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Mini-PCI-E-to-PCI-E-Express-1X-Extension-Cord-Adapter-Card-with-USB-Riser-Card-/161775580004

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Mini-pci-e-to-USB-PCI-e-express-1X-Riser-Extender-adapter-Card-15-25cm-FPC-Cable-/221795082895

Comment: Does the Magewell card show any indication that it is powered up? e.g. LEDs lit up when physically installed. The adapter you are using get it's +5VDC for USB and +12VDC for PCIe from an external source (you mention using a different computer for this). One issue could be insufficient or missing +12VDC. Can you check that the adapter is getting +12V using a multimeter? Do you have another PCIe x1 card to try in the adapter?  I think it's either a Voltage supply issue or an issue with the adapter itself (check out the pin to pin connections with multimeter)

Comment: Another thought - Assuming +12VDC is good to the magewell card, you also need to make sure that power cycles are fairly well synchronized. If the device isn't powered up from it's external source, or it doesn't power cycle at all when the host computer does, you could get some nasty combination of ACPI misconfiguration and/or PCIe bus errors. I'm sure you ruled this out,you should have a common supply for board / motherboard. The std perip. power cables (thicker, usually white) carry +5 and +12, as do the sata power cables. It's not plug and play, but you could wire it up yourself (carefully).

Comment: Unfortunately the Magewell card doesn't have any indication LED. I have already verified +5V and +12V DC on the power connectors on the adapter but i haven't checked them on the PCIe slot. I am also planning to try another PCIe x1 card in the same slot. I will also ensure to switch the power to card before switching on the Gigabyte. Thank you @Argonauts I will look into into and update accordingly.

Answer (score -3):

It's likely an mSATA port, and not a miniPCIE.
Both look very much alike.

https://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/mSATA-SSD-mSATA-solid-state-drive